# How to fetch email contacts by using GData

Tags: ios, objective-c, gdata-api

i am trying to fetch email contacts from users to display inside the App.i am strugling to intialize GData in my code.i am getting some Error. is it possible to give any tutorials.or can anybody help me to solve this Errors.

```
        GDataEntryContact *contact = [contacts objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *ContactName = [[[contact name] fullName] contentStringValue];
    GDataEmail *email = [[contact emailAddresses] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Error:

```
-[GDataEntryBase name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddcc081
-[GDataEntryBase emailAddresses]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddcc081
```

Thanks in Advance.

----** Solved **---- 
//For Reference

```
- (void)contactsFetchTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
       finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedContact *)feed
                  error:(NSError *)error {
GDataFeedContact *mContactFeed;
if (error) {
    NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Fetch error :%@", [error description]);
}else{//--If Login is success
NSArray *entries = [mContactFeed entries];
NSArray *contacts = [feed entries];

for (int i = 0; i < [contacts count]; i++) {
    GDataEntryContact *contact = [contacts objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *ContactName = [[[contact name] fullName] contentStringValue];
    GDataEmail *email = [[contact emailAddresses] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *ContactEmail = [email address];

    if ([ContactName length] == 0) {
        ContactName = @"Empty";
    }
    if ([ContactEmail length] > 0) {
        //Save email
    }
}}
```

Comment: are you getting the solution if find soln share with me.

Comment: am not sure.Also i forgot this post.do you use to log for `[[[contact name] fullName] contentStringValue]` value ? if else remove it.

Comment: sorry i remember this thing alone as it was not so complicated while solving this issue.now i checked my code.it still remains same , but i have commented those logs alone.

Comment: are you get solution for this if get siolution please give me i am stuck in for two days...

Comment: please help me. or post your answer here. so other will take refrance from this..

Comment: do you log `[[[contact name] fullName] contentStringValue]`. ?if so please remove it.

Comment: ok.i will check that code and post back here.

Comment: Hi Namo - Check the Updated code above,try it and reply whether it was helpful for you.

Comment: thank you Gray code i will try this and let you know...

Comment: @Gray code but how this method is being called.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43331/discussion-between-namo-and-grey-code)